# Java - JAXB XML unmarshal with optional fields

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception, jaxb

I have issues with accessing fields of unmarshalled XML files, which contain optional tags. Here is a simple example I made up for a more complex case:

```
<people>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <id>222</id>
            <pets>
                <pet>
                    <name age="2">Harry</name>
                </pet>
                <pet>
                    <name>Tiffany</name>
                </pet>
            </pets>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>111</id>
            <pets>
                <pet value="1"></pet>
            </pets>
            <spouse>Frank</spouse>
        </person>
    </persons>
</people>
```

Notice that the second person has a spouse and the first does not. Additionally, the pets of the first person have names and the pets of the second person do not. The pet named Harry has also an age attribute. What I'm trying to show is that my XML files can have varying data, because of optional fields.

Here are my model classes for JAXB:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class People {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="person")
    private List<Person> persons;

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons= persons;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlElement
    private int id;

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="pet")
    private List<Pet> pets;

    @XmlElement
    private String spouse;

    //getters and setters

}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class pet {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int age;

    @XmlValue
    private String name;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Now, let's say that I just want to print all names of pets.

```
for (Person person : people.getPersons()) {
    for (Pet pet : person.getPets()) {
        System.out.println("Pet name: " + pet.getName());
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException`, if an inner tag is missing. Interestingly enough though, if you just search for a field in the people layer, it will just skip the XML tag as if it does not exist, like:

```
for (Person person : people.getPersons()) {
    System.out.println("Spouse: " + person.getSpouse());
}
```

The above command works even though the first person does not have a spouse. It just provides the string "null", which works well for me.

A solution that I've tried - wrap each field in an `if` or `try-catch` statement (I prefer not to do this as there are hundreds of XML tags). Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of XML annotations missing. Furthermore, the first two examples are the same. Also, `people.getPerson().get(i).getPet.getName` does not make sense, since `getPet` is a method and returns a list?

Comment: Your XML example may be wrong, too, because `<pet>` does not include `<name>`, but `Dog` and `Cat`.

Comment: You're right, I apologize if it was a bad example but I just made this on the fly to to illustrate a simple example. Those fields can be replaced with anything. As for the .get(i), I'll update my post to include a for loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` in your example is quite obvious.

```
System.out.println("Pet name: " + people.getPerson().get(i).getPet().getName());
```

The problem is, when you have no pets,`getPet()` returns `null`. Subsequently, you call `getName()` on `null`, hence you get the exception. In your second example, the execption does not occur, because `getSpouse()` returns `null`, but `System.out.println(...)` converts it into the string *null* automatically.

Even though it may seem tedious, you will have to check your attributes explicitly for `null`, as you traverse your lists or fields. **Never** do that with `try-catch`! Exception handling is a heavy mechanism and you should never abuse this concept for `null` checks.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My worst fear came true, I guess - checking all fields to see if they are null or not. But isn't this bad practice to create a bunch of if statements for each field? Any possible way to create a separate method that checks this?

Comment: The problem is, that your fields are optional. In case a field is _required_, you can annotate them, so JAXB checks the fields and raises an error on `null`. However, if the fields are optional, you basically say: I expect a concrete value (an `object != null`) or `null`, both is **valid** input. As in every other application, you handle these data in your program logic, which includes checking for `null`. What do you mean by "create a bunch of if statements for each field"? What do you actually want to achieve by this?

Comment: What I meant by "creating a bunch of if-statements", is wrapping if-statements to see if XML tags under "person" are null or not. So if it is null, then it can be skipped. This is to achieve capturing all data fields within an XML. What did you* mean by "checking [all] attributes explicitly for null"?

Comment: By _explicitly checking for `null`_ i mean `if (instance != null) { ... }`. In this case, you must check for `null`, so you cannot avoid if-statements. However, if you have a list `persons` and you check `if (persons != null) { ... }` then you have one if-statement. Then you can use `for (person personInList : persons) { ... }`. In the loop body, all `personInList  != null`. If you do not want to iterate over the list, but check if there are persons, just use `if (persons != null && persons.size() > 0)`. This way, it is not as verbose as you might think. Does that help you?

Comment: Hey @thatguy, I know this thread is a bit old but could another alternative use the Optional class (introduced in Java 8)? I found this link and it seems to align to this very problem (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html). However, I'm not too sure if I need to encapsulate every member attribute for all children within JAXB?